# How to have colors as options in a cell of a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I know that in a table I can write something like :

```html
<td>
  <select style="width:100%">
    <option value="no">Select</option>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

so in that cell I will have a drop down menu, with "Yes" and "No" options.

But I want to have colors as my options, so when a user clicks on a cell, he will see a drop down menu and can see for example red and green colors as options.

I do not know if it is possible to do this and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: Correct me if I didn't understand your issue; Why not just replace the option values/names with colours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CSS [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) property to style the options as red or green:

```css
option[value="green"] {
  background-color: green;
}
option[value="red"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table style="border: 1px solid lightgray">
  <tr>
    <td>Make Selection
    <td>
      <select style="width:100%">
        <option value="red">Select</option>
        <option value="green">&nbsp;</option>
        <option value="red">&nbsp;</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

If you want to change the style of the `select` or the `td` based on the selected option, that's not possible with pure CSS; you'll have to use JavaScript for that. When the value of the select changes, update it's style based on the selected value. The example below uses jQuery, but this is possible in vanilla JS too.

```js
$(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $(this)[0].className = $(this).val();
  });
});
```

```css
select.green, option[value="green"] { background-color: green; }
select.red, option[value="red"] { background-color: red; }
select option { background-color: lightgray; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <select style="width:130px">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="green">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="red">&nbsp;</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am sorry I was not clear. The yes and no options is for one cell. The colors option is for another cell.

Comment: @user3530082 Same concept applies--just replace the values "yes" and "no" with color names or whatever other key you want to use, and update the css selector. See update above.

Comment: thank you. But after selecting for example red color, the  cell dose not get red.@nbrooks

Comment: @user3530082 Updated to account for changing the color of the parent. (For future, the more details like that you include in your question, the more likely that answers will match your reqs.)

Comment: @nrbooks, thank you so much,I tested above and it worked. Just I have a question, the first two part that you wrote, should I write them in the same file as the third part?

Comment: @user3530082 You can put them all in the same file, or have separate files for your html, css, and javascript. It's pretty easy to find how to put those together by googling or looking at any webpages source code. If you want them all in the same file, the JS has to be wrapped in `<script></script>` tags, and the css has to be wrapped in `<style></style>` tags. Style tags are usually in the `<head>`, script tags can be anywhere, though I think at the end of the `<body>` is now considered ideal when possible.